# SQL merge using a CAST column

Tags: sql, merge, casting, alias

I want to perform a SQL merge but on columns that have been CAST in the select statement.

I have tried this code:

```
CREATE TABLE test 
AS
    SELECT 
        a.ID, a.curr_bus_date, a.branch_no, a.account_no, 
        CAST(b.sortcodeinfo AS int) AS sortcode,  
        CAST(b.accountnumberinfo AS int) AS accountnumber,
        b.curr_bus_date  
    FROM 
        TABLE1 AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        TABLE2 AS b ON a.branch_no = sortcode 
                    AND a.account_no = accountnumber
                    AND a.curr_bus_date = b.curr_bus_date
    WHERE 
        MONTH(curr_bus_date) = 11  
        AND YEAR(curr_bus_date) = 2022
```

And I get the error:

> DatabaseError: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the StartQueryExecution operation: line 2:37: mismatched input '.'. Expecting: ',', 'EXCEPT', 'FROM', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'INTERSECT', 'LIMIT', 'OFFSET', 'ORDER', 'UNION', 'WHERE',

I can't quite get the syntax correct for the cast variables I wish to merge on. I need to do this casting as the variables are different types and otherwise won't merge.. The volumes in the table are too big to do the casting as separate exercises.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

The names created in the `select` clause are not yet available in the `ON` join conditions. You will have to repeat the `cast` expressions there.

Additionally, for the `WHERE` clause, this will be **MUCH** more efficient:

```
WHERE curr_bus_date >= '20221101' and curr_bus_date < '20221201'
```

Before, the database had to run the month and year functions for the `curr_bus_date` column on *every row in the table*, even rows you won't need. Using a function or otherwise altering a field like `curr_bus_date` also means the result of the expression no longer matches any index values. Any index on the column would be worthless for the query. Writing the conditions so the column values remain unaltered means indexes can still work, which can be HUGE for performance.

Comment: Thanks Joel.  I'm still struggling. I now have cast(b.sortcodeinfo as int),cast(b.accountnumberinfo as int) in my select statement and     on a.branch_no = cast(b.sortcodeinfo as int) 
    and a.account_no = cast(b.accountnumberinfo as int) 
    and a.curr_bus_date = b.curr_bus_date          as my join. I'm getting the error OperationalError: INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast '' to INT

Comment: Try [`Try_Cast()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), or `NULLIF()`: `cast(nullif(b.sortcodeinfo,'') as int)`

Comment: Thanks for this, my code seems to run now without syntax errors. As the tables are huge I do need to make it more efficient as you say. When I try the curr_bus_date syntax you suggested I get the error '>=' cannot be applied to date, varchar(8)

I tried CAST(curr_bus_date AS Date) on the select, join and where statements but got the same error.  Any help on this would be great and many thanks for your help thus far!!

Comment: If the formal type of the `curr_bus_date` column is not date, datetime, or datetime2, you have a very serious problem with your database. Otherwise, use the string literals exactly as I provided them.

Comment: Thanks Joel, you've been a great help